# After successfully inserted data in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0, why the cluster reported 507 type error?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

The cluster of Apache IoTDB reported a 507 error: `o.a.i.d.m.s.SchemaRegionMemoeyImpl:1148-Failed to read tag and attribute info because null`. After I successfully inserted three time series using the java interface, this error is prompted. Currently I use Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB. Anyone know why I cannot insert data after these three successful ones?